# Python "Import missingno" results in "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, importerror, site-packages

I am using jupyter nb running python 3.9.1 using pip to install modules etc.
All imports work smoothly except missingno.
All the modules being imported are located in the same location *Python39\lib\site-packages* but missingno results in Import Error.

The missingno module had been imported and it has run smoothly before but after a kernel restart, the Import Error cropped up.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fad26a6fb4fe> in <module>
      6 #Visualization
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 8 import missingno 
      9 import seaborn as sns 
     10 plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\missingno\missingno.py in <module>
      6 import seaborn as sns
      7 import pandas as pd
----> 8 from .utils import nullity_filter, nullity_sort
      9 import warnings
     10 

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How to fix it?

I have tried to delete the missingno files and reinstalling it using `pip install missingno` but nothing works.
Running Python in shell and importing missingno, I still get the same error. There is nothing fancy in my code, a simple, generic import which showed no signs of error before kernel restart.

```
>>> import missingno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\OK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\missingno\missingno.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .utils import nullity_filter, nullity_sort
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Open the `missingno.py` file in site-packages. Change `from .utils ...` to `from utils ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the `missingno.py` file in site-packages.

Change

```
from .utils import nullity_filter, nullity_sort
```

to

```
from utils import nullity_filter, nullity_sort
```

Comment: Tried it but this time the import error is as follows,       
   ```>>> import missingno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\OK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\missingno\missingno.py", line 8, in <module>
    from utils import nullity_filter, nullity_sort
ImportError: cannot import name 'nullity_filter' from 'utils' (C:\Users\OK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py)```

Comment: Try this: `from utils import *`

Comment: @capt.bandwidth I can't see the error. Please resend it

Comment: No import error this time but a new error arose. 
```>>> missingno.matrix(train, figsize = (30,10))

~\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\missingno\missingno.py in matrix(df, filter, n, p, sort, figsize, width_ratios, color, fontsize, labels, sparkline, inline, freq, ax)
     33     :return: If `inline` is False, the underlying `matplotlib.figure` object. Else, nothing.
     34     """
---> 35     df = nullity_filter(df, filter=filter, n=n, p=p)
     36     df = nullity_sort(df, sort=sort, axis='columns')

NameError: name 'nullity_filter' is not defined.```

Comment: @ DapperDuck Hey, any possible suggestions to this problem.

Comment: Oh, my bad I didn't see your comment. I can't seem to find the reason why this occurs, but it might be due to matplotlib and inline, because you are using a notebook